# How to output not as plain text

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I have install a **joomla plugin** by the name [**AllVideos Plugin**](http://www.joomlaworks.net/extensions/free-premium/allvideos). All I have to do is to put some tags like this `{youtube}h2TLC0zGwKE{/youtube}` somewhere in to my site and my video shows up!

In this point I need your help... In to my **php** code I have add a **hidden textbox** that holds video's source and a **div** that will show video when I click on an **image** using **javascript**.

Part of **PHP** code

```
<input id="video_url" name="video_url" type="hidden" value="" />
<div id="video"></div>
```

Part of **JAVASCRIPT** code

```
var Open      = String.fromCharCode(123,121,111,117,116,117,98,101,125); // {youtube}
var Close     = String.fromCharCode(123,47,121,111,117,116,117,98,101,125); // {/youtube}
var video     = document.getElementById("video");
var video_url = document.getElementById("video_url");
...
video.innerHTML =  Open+video_url.value+Close;
```

The problem is that youtube tags appear just as plain text! Take a look at this image:
[image: Screenshot of image]

Any idea how I will make it work?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs before JavaScript, that's how the client-server model works. You'd have to re-create the same functionality in JavaScript, which is fairly trivial. Here's an example:

```
function youtubeVideo(str){
  return str.replace(
    /\{youtube\}(\w+)\{\/youtube\}/g,
    '<iframe width="420" height="315"\
    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1"\
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
  );
}

youtubeVideo('{youtube}HzeZhCt5PVA{/youtube}');
```

That should help you out.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/TpRw3/